# How can I select a subset of keys in a dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have this large dictionary

```
{
        "configGlossary:installationAt": "Philadelphia, PA",
        "configGlossary:adminEmail": "ksm@pobox.com",
        "configGlossary:poweredBy": "Cofax",
        "configGlossary:poweredByIcon": "/images/cofax.gif",
        "configGlossary:staticPath": "/content/static",
        "templateProcessorClass": "org.cofax.WysiwygTemplate",
        "templateLoaderClass": "org.cofax.FilesTemplateLoader",
        "templatePath": "templates",
        "templateOverridePath": "",
        "defaultListTemplate": "listTemplate.htm",
        "defaultFileTemplate": "articleTemplate.htm",
        "useJSP": false,
        "jspListTemplate": "listTemplate.jsp",
        "jspFileTemplate": "articleTemplate.jsp",
        "cachePackageTagsTrack": 200,
        "cachePackageTagsStore": 200,
        "cachePackageTagsRefresh": 60,
        "cacheTemplatesTrack": 100,
        "cacheTemplatesStore": 50,
        "cacheTemplatesRefresh": 15,
        "cachePagesTrack": 200,
        "cachePagesStore": 100,
        "cachePagesRefresh": 10,
        "cachePagesDirtyRead": 10,
        "searchEngineListTemplate": "forSearchEnginesList.htm",
        "searchEngineFileTemplate": "forSearchEngines.htm",
        "searchEngineRobotsDb": "WEB-INF/robots.db",
        "useDataStore": true,
        "dataStoreClass": "org.cofax.SqlDataStore",
        "redirectionClass": "org.cofax.SqlRedirection",
        "dataStoreName": "cofax",
        "dataStoreDriver": "com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver",
        "dataStoreUrl": "jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver://LOCALHOST:1433;DatabaseName=goon",
        "dataStoreUser": "sa",
        "dataStorePassword": "dataStoreTestQuery",
        "dataStoreTestQuery": "SET NOCOUNT ON;select test='test';",
        "dataStoreLogFile": "/usr/local/tomcat/logs/datastore.log",
        "dataStoreInitConns": 10,
        "dataStoreMaxConns": 100,
        "dataStoreConnUsageLimit": 100,
        "dataStoreLogLevel": "debug",
        "maxUrlLength": 500}
```

I need a dictionary with reduce key value pairs for example

```
{       
        "cachePackageTagsTrack": 200,
        "cachePackageTagsStore": 200,
        "cachePackageTagsRefresh": 60,
        "cacheTemplatesTrack": 100,
        "cacheTemplatesStore": 50,
        "cacheTemplatesRefresh": 15,
        "cachePagesTrack": 200,
        "cachePagesStore": 100,
        "cachePagesRefresh": 10,
        "cachePagesDirtyRead": 10
}
```

There are no dictionary methods which can do this too.

I have large set of similar data which is run in a loop

I am looking for fast and efficient way to reduce the dictionary

Comment: Why not pick out the keys you want in a plain old dict comprehension?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What actually is the difficulty here? In particular, **what is the rule that tells you** which keys to keep?

Answer (score 0):

As a quick alternative, you can store the keys you want to keep somewhere and then loop through them:

```
keys_list = ["cachePackageTagsTrack",
             "cachePackageTagsStore",
             "cachePackageTagsRefresh",
             "cacheTemplatesTrack",
             "cacheTemplatesStore",
             "cacheTemplatesRefresh",
             "cachePagesTrack",
             "cachePagesStore",
             "cachePagesRefresh",
             "cachePagesDirtyRead"]

my_new_dict = {key: my_dict.get(key, "") for key in keys_list}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dictionary comprehension to create a new dictionary that only contains the key-value pairs you want to keep.

```
# keys to keep
keys_to_keep = ["cachePackageTagsTrack", "cachePackageTagsStore", "cachePackageTagsRefresh", 
                "cacheTemplatesTrack", "cacheTemplatesStore", "cacheTemplatesRefresh", 
                "cachePagesTrack", "cachePagesStore", "cachePagesRefresh", "cachePagesDirtyRead"]

# create new dictionary with only the keys to keep
reduced_dict = {key: large_dict[key] for key in keys_to_keep if key in large_dict}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is if you don't want to create a separate list of keys is to filter the keys to the ones you are interested that have a common pattern when creating the reduced dict, in this case, they all start with the substring `cache`:

```
reduced_dict = {key: value for key, value in my_dict.items() if key.startswith('cache')}
```